# php file text with added a line every time in mysql base value data

Tags: php, mysql, file, text, line

I have an file text with several informations, i want read the file
and cut the data inside:

My file looks like this :

```
firstname;lastname;computer;ip
firstname;lastname;computer;ip
firstname;lastname;computer;ip
```

I want load that file in my mysql base each time a line is added.
I start with this script but i do not understand why the first names are not added in my database
Here my script :

```
 <?php
$data = fopen("./session_name", "r");
$i = 0; 

while ($line = fgets($data))
{
    $i++;
    $line = explode(';', $line);
    $two = explode(';', $line[0]);
    foreach($two as $t)
    {
      $insert = "INSERT INTO `session_test`(`prenom`, `nom`, `computer`, `adress_ip`) VALUES ('" . trim($t) . "',"","","")";
    mysql_query($insert_data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First thing first, add debugs to see if you have a problem in the code. mysql_query($insert_data) or die(mysql_error()); also, print_r($two) to see if your array is created as expected.

Comment: `$line[0]` shouldn't have any `;`s because your previous explode removed them all. `$line[0]` should be `firstname`.

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = fopen("./session_name", "r");
$query = "INSERT INTO `session_test`(`prenom`, `nom`, `computer`, `adress_ip`) VALUES ";
while ($line = fgets($data)) {
  $exploded = explode(';', $line);
  $values[] = vsprintf("('%s','%s','%s','%s')",array_map('trim',$exploded));
}
$query .= implode(',',$values);
// mysqli or PDO code to query;
```